# How to refresh a <ul> tag after <li> tags are appended to <ul> after executing the ajax call using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

While page loading, I am invoking ajax call to servlet. The servlet returns some json data, and anyhow I appended that data to the `<ul>` tag in the form of `<li>`. I need to refresh that `<ul>` tag only after ajax success call with the dynamic data from the servlet. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide what you already tried - and for example your html code and an example of how the returned data looks like?

Comment: Any basic jQuery ajax tutorial will cover this. Try some of those and when you have specific questions and code with it please come back and ask then.

Comment: As @JonP said you could give the code to refresh `<ul>` tag in the `done()` or `success()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Have the id attached to the `<li>` : `<li data-itemid=id></li>`

Then, when there is a successful ajax update, you can just delete that `<li>` by `$('li[data-itemid=id]').remove();` and add the updated version by using your existing code that.